# Add together cells depending on value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to write a sum-formula in Google Sheet that would add together all the values in the E-column which number in the F-column for example is "2"?

[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO4y9.png)

Hope the question makes sense,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solution #1

Make a pivot table

### solution #2

```
=QUERY(E2:F,"select F,sum(E) where F is not null group by F  ")
```

Comment: Thanks. I played around with it and ended up with this: =sum(QUERY(E4:F;"select E WHERE F = 2")). Thanks :D